# Inverse quantile function for $\sin^2(x)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

What is the transformation which takes the standard uniform distribution $U[0,1]$ to the following probability density function $f$:

$$f(x)=\sin^{2}x$$

Where $x\in\left[0,\pi\right]$ and $f\in[0,1]$. (This is useful for distributing points on $S^3$, the hypersphere in 4D, because the Jacobian of the transformation from uniform rectilinear coordinates to spherical coordinates creates a term containing $\sin^{2}x$.) Following the method of [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), we need to integrate and invert the PDF; applying the standard uniform distribution to the inverted CDF gives the desired distribution.

[image: PDF(X)]

The CDF is easy enough to calculate:

$$F(x) = \frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\sin2x+C$$

Where $C$ is determined by the bounds. However, I don't see how to invert this function (regardless of $C$). Here's a numerical simulation of the inverse after $F(x)$ is normalized to [0,1] by multiplying by $\frac{2}{\pi}$:

[image: inverse CDF]

Although the CDF appears to be 1-to-1 and onto in the relevant domain, I don't see how to get a true analytical inverse because the combination of $arcsin$ and the linear term just doesn't work out. I tried a Taylor's series approximation and got $\sqrt[3]{3U}$, but that only works for small $U$, say $U\in\left[0,0.5\right]$, and it definitely doesn't cover the full range of $\sin^{2}x$.

**The question is how do you transform the standard uniform distribution to $\sin^{2}x$, as stated above. Uniform random number generators are readily available, but I want to draw samples from the $\sin^{2}x$ distribution.**

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Clarified question above.

Comment: Your $f$ misses a factor $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: normalized F(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the wikipedia article you quote, there is probably no simple analytic expression solving your equation. But, in the same article, they say that approximating the icdf by polynomials is very efficient and your cdf seem to be very smooth.

Comment: I was really hoping that someone else was better at finding function inverses than I am because F(x) looks so simple. If nobody else comes up with an inverse, I'll just use polynomials and/or numerical interpolation and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Forget $F$, here's a much easier way to sample from the distribution you want. Draw a sample $(x,y)$ from the uniform distribution on $[0,\pi/2]\times[0,1]$, *i.e.*, the left half of the rectangle in your first plot. If it lies below the graph of $y=\sin^2x$, return $x$. Otherwise, return $x+\pi/2$.

This is just [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) together with the observation that you can take the region below the graph in $[\pi/2,\pi]$, flip it over, and fit it exactly into the region above the graph in $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Rejection sampling is disappointingly inefficient when starting with the uniform distribution because most practical uniform generators will become periodic too quickly. Still, your observation about symmetry is clever.

Comment: There is absolutely no rejection actually going on in this solution though. I don't understand why you're happy using the uniform distribution for inverse transform sampling but not for this.